# Is this STM32F based CAN bus circuit ok?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, circuit-design, stm32f10x

So this is my first time moving away from Arduino based projects and I am now planning a project using the STM32F105RBT6.

It is a simple CAN bus analyser with some leds. I may add some extra i/o in the future.

As for the power supply, I plan to have it powered from a 8-30v input or the USB port. I think the attached power supply circuit should work.

I have used parts of example schematics and the schematics from development and evaluation boards I have found online.

Will the attached circuit work? I am mainly concerned about the STM32 circuit along with the power and usb.

[image]

Comment: What does generate the VDD voltage ?

Comment: Maybe.  You don't need to wire up full JTAG as SWDCLK and SWDIO, NRST, and a way to monitor VDD are enough, leaving your board simpler and more I/Os for other things. Definitely bring a UART to a header though as you may need it for output while getting the USB working.

Comment: I have now edited it with the power supply circuit. Thanks

Comment: Could you give part names on those power supply parts?

Comment: Still not sure what the part after the USB connector is, but I can't see why it would be necessary. Hook the USB up directly to the micro. Also having trouble finding the mic4608bm. I also think you may want some power isolation. What takes precedence, USB port or Vin. I generally try to avoid backpowering by choosing one over the other and then isolating with a dual PFET.

Comment: My mistake! I have now edited the image, its MIC4680BM.
What would you recommend in regards to power isolation?
VIN would have precedence but I don't think it would really matter, the circuit shouldn't use any more current than a USB port can provide.

Comment: @TerryGould The switcher looks fine. And now that I think about it, you could probably be clever on sensing USB data connection and use it to toggle the SHDN pin on the switcher. Then the USB would take precedence. What I actually mean is you might have a PFET from VIN to the switcher and when you have USB power it shuts the FET off.

Comment: I don't know what is that component after the USB connector. If it's an usual ESD protector with TVS diodes like this (http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CM1224-D.PDF) then it should not be connected in series with the chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to put in a voltage regulator, driven from the USB's 5V pin or else have an external 3.3V regulator. You could use a low-dropout linear regulator, but in my design I used a TPS563200. You have to do this, as the maximum voltage is set at 4.0V.

STM32s BOOT0 pin is not a regular logic pin. You want to connect BOOT0 through a 10K resistor before connecting the other end to GND or VDD.

You should double-check with the datasheets, but I believe you need to connect PA9 (OTG_FS_VBUS) to the USB's 5V pin, and to support/sense USB OTG you'll also need to connect PA10 (OTG_FS_ID). It also looks like you've connected the USB shield directly to ground. There are many recommendations out there, but the one I use is to connect GND to SHIELD with a 1Mohm resistor in parallel with a 0.1uF capacitor.

Typically, the reset switch should be in parallel with a capacitor. However, I like to use a dedicated chip for this, for instance the APX823.

Finally, take a good look at the reference design (http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00164185.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the question with my planned power supply circuit.
Do I need to add a 100R resistor between the BOOT0 and the pull down resistor?

Comment: @Terry Gould I believe you can just tie BOOT0. You should also do the same for BOOT1 on PB2

Comment: For NRST you need a decoupling cap to ground and maybe an RC filter. No need to tie it high.

Comment: Would I ever need to toggle either BOOT pin?

Comment: @Terry Gould If you want to flash via UART over a bootloader then you need BOOT1. Boot0 tells you if you are writing firmware to main flash, which it looks like, so you can keep that down.

Comment: AFAIK, STM's boot pins should not be left floating, and by the examples I've seen should always have a resistor tied to VCC or GND. To me it indicates that there's no internal pull-up/pull-down on these pins. I've seen 10K resistors and 47K resistors.

Comment: @Pål-KristianEngstad Wholeheartedly agree. I forgot to put the amount in. Pulling down with a 10k is fine. And GND is what you want here so that you don't always actuvate the different boot methods.

Comment: Ill never flash over UART only though USB or SWD/JTAG. So what should I do to the boot pins, can they permanently be tied or will I ever need to toggle them?

In regards to the USB VBUS, If I connect the USB 5+ to (OTG_FS_VBUS) how can I stop it from becoming high when the board is only being powered from VIN?

Comment: If you never will change boot mode, then tie BOOT0 --- 10K ---- GND. For the OTG_FS_VBUS, a diode should do the trick.

Comment: STM reference manual shows examples using their STMPS2141STR switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your Oscillator design is missing the series resistor between OSC_OUT and X1.
Have a look at [reference design](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00164185.pdf) section 2.1 fig. 7
[image]